# Azure DevOps upload git hook to existing repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

Is it possible to upload a git hook (`.git\hooks`) to a existing repository?
Is there any way to access the `.git` directory inside a Azure DevOps repo?

Something like:

```
https://server/collection/_git/project?path=%.git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the hooks inside the `.git` folder is in the client side, not in the server side. for each client the hooks can be different.

There is a [Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365841/add-git-pre-receive-hooks.html) to Git pre-receive hooks in the server level.