# Azure-Devops Create new repo with default git hook script

Tags: git, azure-devops

I would like to enforce commit-msg git hook in each new new created repository in our Azure-Devops environment. Is there a way to configure Azure-Devops to create new repositories with .git/hooks that contains my commit-msg script?

Comment: As far as I know Azure DevOps does not support git style commit hooks. You have to use those provided in Azure DevOps. If your intent is to have them added when cloning, that is not possible to do automatically, you have to have each user add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, I am afraid this is currently not achievable in Azure devops. The hooks inside the `.git` folder is in the client side, not in the server side. For each client the hooks can be different.

In addition, currently we have to make members run the `git config core.hooksPath .githooks` command manually to enable custom hooks. We can't avoid a manual step here cause git hooks is designed to trigger actions at certain points per user instead of per team.

Here are some ticket you can refer to:

- [Azure DevOps upload git hook to existing repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931489/azure-devops-upload-git-hook-to-existing-repository)
- [Azure DevOps force core.hooksPath after clone a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885967/azure-devops-force-core-hookspath-after-clone-a-repository)